# Create URL column link to open selected document properties in sharepoint 0365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have been looking for a way to create a URL in a column that will open the properties of a selected document in a document library. Has anyone been able to do this?

For instance:
Select the document then click link to open the properties side menu.
Instead of clicking "..." hover to more > hover to properties, then select properties.
I'm trying to create an obvious one click solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JSON column formatting' **button** type, **customRowAction**, and **editProps** option, you can have a button by clicking which the property window will open for viewing/editing.

See an example below:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "button",
  "txtContent": "Edit",
  "customRowAction": {
    "action": "editProps"
  },
  "style": {
    "background-color": "Transparent",
    "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
    "border": "none",
    "cursor": "pointer",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "outline": "none"
  }
}
```

Note: Add a Single line of text column and format it with JSON above

[image]